# A problem when integrating $\int \frac{a}{x^2 + 1}\text{ } dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

*I’m still not an expert in integration, and I’m still learning, so sorry if it’s a trivial question:*

Here’s the general integral:

$$\int \frac{a}{x^2 + 1}\text{ } dx, a \in \mathbb R$$

I know that this antiderivative is $a \tan^{-1} (x)$.

Now, I want to compute

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{a}{x^2 + 1}\text{ } dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{a}{x^2 + 1} \text{ } dx$$

This basically means

$$\left(a \lim\limits_{T\to \infty} \tan^{-1}(T)\right) - 0$$

I’ve heard a lot of people say it’s $\frac{a\pi}{2}$.

HOWEVER, the tangent also approaches infinity at any $x = \frac{a(2n+1)\pi}{2}$.

So really the entire area under that curve from negative to positive infinity, should be $a\pi$ but is equal to $a(2n+1)\pi = 2na\pi + a\pi$ by integrating algebraically.

What am I missing, and what should we do for other situations like this where the periodicity of the antiderivative can give multiple solutions?

Comment: One thing to note is that integrals are continuous. This means that the left and right side of the integral must be on the same "strip" of tangent's inverse. And no matter which strip you consider, it increase by $\pi$ as you go from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not just any $y$ with $\tan(y) = x$, it is specifically the one in the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.  So yes,
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

In ITF the range of $tan^{-1}x$ is widely considered as from $(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ even though like you said $tanx$ has multiple solutions for any $x = \alpha$. However for $tan^{-1}(\alpha)$ we only consider the solution that lies in the mentioned range. The reason is because when we choose to invert a function we make sure its bijective in the given domain. Since $tanx$ isnt bijective in its domain we just take a sub-set of its domain where its bijective and then find its inverse corresponding to that part only. The widely accepeted sub-set of the domain $tanx$ we used to find its inverse is $(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

However for the issue your facing its not necessary to follow the strict range given above, but we must make sure its bijective. For example in an interval from $(\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2},\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$) $tanx$ is always bijective. So on integrating and applying the limits we get $2(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} -n\pi)$ which is $\pi$.